# How to load an image and access it from everywhere?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to browse an image from form window. Also I created a class and created some filters. I can read this image from form.

My goal is declare it in my class. And use this image in everywhere. But I don't know how can I do this.

```
private void btn_BROWSE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog imge = new OpenFileDialog(); 
    imge.Filter = "Extensions |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff|"
                  + "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
                  + "Zip Files|*.zip;*.rar";
    imge.ShowDialog(); 
    string imgepath = imge.FileName;
    pBox_SOURCE.ImageLocation = imgepath;//i'm browsing an image
}
```

```
private void sliderKernel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap OriginalImage = new Bitmap(pBox_SOURCE.Image);
}
```

```
class Filters
{ 
    // (i would like to initialize my image in here not in form :) ) 
}
```

Comment: Is this Winforms?

Comment: Yes it is Winfoms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define an abstract class Filter and implement every filter as an heir of that class.

```
public abstract class Filter
{   
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

    public abstract void Apply();
}
```

An implementation would be:

```
public class SliderKernel : Filter
{   
    public overrides void Apply()
    {
        //manipulates the Image property
    }
}
```

If you want to use that image everywhere you should declare it as a static member of a class:

```
public static class ImageContainer
{
     public static Bitmap Image { get; set; }
}
```

You can use all this in your form code like this:

```
private void btn_BROWSE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog imge = new OpenFileDialog(); 
    imge.Filter = "Extensions |*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff|"
                  + "BMP|*.bmp|GIF|*.gif|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff|"
                  + "Zip Files|*.zip;*.rar";
    imge.ShowDialog(); 
    string imgepath = imge.FileName;
    pBox_SOURCE.ImageLocation = imgepath;//i'm browsing an image

    //save the image to the container
    ImageContainer.Image = new Bitmap(pBox_SOURCE.Image);
}

private void sliderKernel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Filter filter = new SliderKernel () { Image = ImageContainer.Image };
    filter.Apply();
}
```

Comment: I will use first and third code parts in my class. But i didn't understand second one where will i use it?

Comment: The second part of the code is an implementation of what a specific filter does, so, that code won't be in the form code. A new filter should implement the Filter class. The 3rd part is the code you post, what must change in order to use the new class hierarchy and the static container

Comment: If you found it useful, please, mark the answer as correct, and vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should turn the image into a byte array**

using the following code and store it in a static class

```
public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      imageIn.Save(ms,imageIn.RawFormat);
      return  ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

**And use this code to turn into a graphic to display in pictureBox**

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: You may consider explain why a byte array is more efficient here.

Comment: Well it may not be more efficient but it is another valid way of doing it